# Way to save all elements inside an array of object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to save all the records value in a variable with delimiter of comma (,). Is there a way to do it?

expected content= 13783107, 13819738, 13819745 ... etc

Here is the content of the file

```
Object {metaData: Array(1), rows: Array(29)}
metaData:Array(1) [Object]
rows:Array(29) [Object, Object, Object, …]
length:29
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {RECORDS: 13783107}
1:Object {RECORDS: 13819738}
2:Object {RECORDS: 13819745}
3:Object {RECORDS: 13819746}
4:Object {RECORDS: 13819747}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected content's type? string?

Answer (score 2):

Say, variable `file` contains the file. Try this:

```
const commaSeparatedRecords = file.rows.map(r => r.RECORDS).join(', ');
console.log(commaSeparatedRecords);
```

> How about adding a single quote (') before and after each number?

```
file.rows.map(r => `'${r.RECORDS}'`).join(', ');
// note backtick
```

Comment: Thank you, the file.rows.map(r => r.RECORDS).join(', ') worked. How about adding a single quote (') before and after each number?

Comment: return backtick'${r.RECORDS}'backtick. Updated answer